# Xcode UI test - UI Testing Failure - Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) when tap on Search field "Cancel' button

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to dismiss the search field by tapping 'Cancel' button in search bar.

The test case is failing to find the cancel button. It was working fine in Xcode 7.0.1

I have added predicate to wait for button to appear. The test case is failing when we tap of "cancel" button

```
let button = app.buttons[“Cancel”]
let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")

expectationForPredicate(existsPredicate, evaluatedWithObject: button, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)

button.tap() // Failing here
```

**logs**:

```
    t =     7.21s     Tap SearchField
t =     7.21s         Wait for app to idle
t =     7.29s         Find the SearchField
t =     7.29s             Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for com.test.mail
t =     7.49s             Find: Descendants matching type SearchField
t =     7.49s             Find: Element at index 0
t =     7.49s             Wait for app to idle
t =     7.55s         Synthesize event
t =     7.84s         Wait for app to idle
t =     8.97s     Type 'vinayak@xmd.net' into
t =     8.97s         Wait for app to idle
t =     9.03s         Find the "Search" SearchField
t =     9.03s             Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for com.test.mail
t =     9.35s             Find: Descendants matching type SearchField
t =     9.35s             Find: Element at index 0
t =     9.36s             Wait for app to idle
t =     9.42s         Synthesize event
t =    10.37s         Wait for app to idle
t =    10.44s     Check predicate `exists == 1` against object `"Cancel" Button`
t =    10.44s         Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for com.test.mail
t =    10.58s         Find: Descendants matching type Button
t =    10.58s         Find: Elements matching predicate '"Cancel" IN identifiers'
t =    10.58s     Tap "Cancel" Button
t =    10.58s         Wait for app to idle
t =    10.64s         Find the "Cancel" Button
t =    10.64s             Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for com.test.mail
t =    10.78s             Find: Descendants matching type Button
t =    10.78s             Find: Elements matching predicate '"Cancel" IN identifiers'
t =    10.79s             Wait for app to idle
t =    11.08s         Synthesize event
t =    11.13s             Scroll element to visible
t =    11.14s             Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button 0x7f7fcaebde40: traits: 8589934593, {{353.0, 26.0}, {53.0, 30.0}}, label: 'Cancel', error: Error -25204 performing AXAction 2003
```

Comment: @ Joe Masilotti any idea?

Comment: Just a sanity check, but is the Cancel button on the screen or does it need to be scrolled to? I know there are still issues where scrolling to elements doesn't always work.

Comment: @JoeMasilotti cancel button is on the screen. Cancel button is system default button which is part of UISearchbar.     It was working fine in Xcode 7.0.1 when I did [self.buttons[@"Cancel"] tap];

Comment: @Vinpai what happens when you add a `app.tables.cells.allElementsBoundByAccessibilityElement.count` before tapping your button? Just curious--this has helped 'refresh' the screen for me at times.

Comment: @Konnor, I tried with API you have suggested, but it is failing when I tap on Cancel button.  When I query application.buttons in debugger, it is showing cancel button

Comment: Having the same exact problem in Xcode 7.1.  The test runs fine in 7.0.1.  For me it is the "Choose" button in the photo library.

Comment: So the issue for me seems to be that the Choose button (that you get from the Photo library picker) is not 'hittable'.  You can't scroll it into position and you cannot wait it out; I mimicked the expectationForPredicate code above replacing 'exists == 1' with 'hittable == 1' to no effect.  I think this is just a bug that Apple needs to fix.  To clarify, you can find the "Choose" button, and .exists returns true, and it is clearly visible on the screen, but .hittable always returns false.  So tap fails.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

I guess here "Cancel" button returns `false` for `hittable` property, that is preventing it from tapping.

If you see `tap()` in documentation it says

```
/*!
 * Sends a tap event to a hittable point computed for the element.
 */
- (void)tap;
```

It seems things are broken with Xcode 7.1. To keep myself (and you too ;)) unblocked from these issues I wrote an extension on `XCUIElement` that allows tap on an element even if it is not hittable. Following can help you.

```
/*Sends a tap event to a hittable/unhittable element.*/
extension XCUIElement {
    func forceTapElement() {
        if self.hittable {
            self.tap()
        }
        else {
            let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0))
            coordinate.tap()
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call as

```
button.forceTapElement()
```

**Update** - For Swift 3 use the following:

```
extension XCUIElement {
    func forceTapElement() {
        if self.isHittable {
            self.tap()
        }
        else {
            let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx:0.0, dy:0.0))
            coordinate.tap()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I was encountering similar problem with `cell.tap()` and this fixed it. Something seems to have changed in Xcode7.1 causing some element to no longer hittable

Comment: I have a custom navigationBar backButtonItem that isn't 'hittable' in Xcode7.1, and this solution works for me `self.app.navigationBars["Nav Title"].staticTexts["Custom Back Btn Title"].forceTapElement()`

Comment: In my case it worked when the tap is in the center of the view. Change the offset to (0.5, 0.5). `let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.5, 0.5))`

Comment: i have a same issue of a normal view with a button, but this sample doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did anyone submit bug report on this to Apple's Radar? I'm using Xcode 7.3(7D175) and have custom `NSControl` with `NSAccessibilityCheckBoxRole`. When I check for `XCTAssertTrue(customCheckBox.hittable)` it fails. Accessibility Inspector didn't find any issues or errors with it, but it can't display it's properties in Inspector panel while hovering it. Looks like I've missed something important.

Comment: Great finding - although this only works most of the times for me. Sometimes it just crashes when trying to tap on the coordinate ?!

Comment: I don't know why, but nothing here works for me. I had to put `sleep(1)`, then XCode can find the damn button.

Comment: I was getting the same issue but not with UIButtons, but with some SpriteKit sprites that had some UIAccessibilityElement associated with them so I could UI-test them. I get the "failed to scroll to visible" error on Xcode 9.4.1 but older devices (tested on iOS 10.3.3 and 11.2.1). As soon as I updated those devices to iOS 11.4.1 the error disappeared. Tested on 5 different devices. They all work after updating.

Comment: One thousand likes to you! In my case, a button in table cell has `isHittable` being `false` because the table view scroll bar could potentially blocking it, while it's not actually blocking it.

Comment: In our case, we need this function because we override `func hitTest()` to forward taps to buttons under the view, which prevents normal UI test interactions for these buttons. In this case, checking `self.isHittable` as suggested was causing an infinite loop. Skipping that `if` clause and directly calling `coordinate.tap()` fixed the issue.

Comment: Still super relevant even today, 4 years later! This fixed the random ass failures I'm getting using GitHub's Action CI build server. Can't for the life of me get the failures to occur locally, even running the same cmd line xcodebuild scripts, but the CI sure does love to fail. thanks!!

Comment: Started seeing this w/existing UI tests running on iOS 14 from Xcode 12 that had worked fine till then (labels inside custom views in the navbar).  This fixed it perfectly..

Comment: Suggestion. The CGVector used in the swift 3 example is the top left computed point of the XCUIElement. Instead, you could do something like `CGVector(dx:0.5, dy:0.5)`, which will be the middle of the element. You'll be less likely to tap something you didn't intend to.

Comment: I faced this issue in Bitrise (Xcode 13) not in my local Xcode but this solution works for Bitrise environment :D thanks @Sandy

Comment: Still seeing this issue in Xcode 14.2. The suggested `forceTapElement` function does not work for me.

Answer (score 14):

For me, the root cause was that the objects I wanted to tap

- have been set to hidden (and back)
- have been removed and re-attached

In both cases the `isAccessibilityElement` property was `false` afterwards. Setting it back to `true` fixed it.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Weirdly, it started happening on iOS 11 (it was working fine on iOS 10).

Answer (score 8):

> This question ranks well for Google queries around the term **"Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button"**. Given the age of the question I was inclined to think this was no longer an issue with the XCUITest framework as the accepted answer suggests.

I found this issue was due to the `XCElement` existing, but being hidden behind the software keyboard. The error is emitted by the framework since it is unable to scroll a view that exists into view to be tappable. In my case the button in question was behind the software keyboard *sometimes*.

I found the iOS Simulator's software keyboard may be toggled off in some cases (eg: on your machine) and toggled on in others (eg: on your CI). In my case I had toggled the software keyboard off on one machine, and by default it was toggled on on others.

#### Solution: Dismiss the keyboard before attempting to tap buttons that may be behind it.

I found tapping somewhere that explicitly dismissed the keyboard before tapping on the button solved my problem in all environments.

I added add some actions to get the current responder to resignFirstResponder. The views behind my text views will force the first responder to resign, so I tap somewhere just underneath the last text area.

```swift
 /// The keyboard may be up, dismiss it by tapping just below the password field
let pointBelowPassword = passwordSecureTextField.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 1))
pointBelowPassword.press(forDuration: 0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the same issue from CI test run, predictive zone of keyboard covers text field. Users are unable to see what they typed. Instead we confirm it is a design bug and change app's layout.

Answer (score 3):

The workaround of Sandy seemed help for a while but then no more - I then changed it like this:

```
func waitAndForceTap(timeout: UInt32 = 5000) {
    XCTAssert(waitForElement(timeout: timeout))
    coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx:0.5, dy:0.5)).tap()
}
```

Main point being that as the issue is that isHittable check throws an exception, I don't do this check at all and go straight for coordinates after the element is found.

Comment: I put this in the `extension XCUIElement` with a couple of small changes: `XCTAssert(self.waitForExistence(timeout: timeout))`, and `timeout` needs to be `Double`

Answer (score 2):

Please check the trait of the element, i was facing the same issue with TableViewSectionHeader, i was trying to tap but it was failing at every point

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if !button.isHittable {
     let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = button.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx:0.0, dy:0.0))
     coordinate.tap()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was having a programmatically added UI element covering the button.

Comment: This is often my issue. Nightmare to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the AppCenter simulator to run the tests, you should make sure that you're running the tests on the same device version than your local simulator. I lost 3 days of work because of this.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of things that can cover your element, I had the RN debugger partially overlayed on top of my icon:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I set a `toolbar` (and `ToolbarItem`) on a `GeometryReader`:

```swift
GeometryReader { proxy in
    ZStack { ... }
}
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button(action: { ... }) {
            Text(Localizable.Global.login.localized)
        }
        .accessibilityIdentifier("welcomeViewLoginButton")
    }
}
```

After setting the toolbar on the `ZStack` instead, the toolbar item button was hittable again.

```swift
GeometryReader { proxy in
    ZStack {
        ...
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Button(action: { ... }) {
                Text(Localizable.Global.login.localized)
            }
            .accessibilityIdentifier("welcomeViewLoginButton")
        }
    }
}
```