# How to correctly UITest an application with UIImagePickerController (or any other native VC)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane-snapshot

I'm trying to automate creating screenshots of my application using [Snapshot](https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot), and all goes well, until I want to navigate through a `UIImagePickerController` which has set `allowsEditing` to `true`.

The weird thing is that in the *iPhone 4s*, *5s* and *6s* simulators this goes just fine, but in the *iPhone 6(s) Plus* the test can't seem to tap the "Choose" ("Kies" in Dutch) button in the cropper view.

[image]

My first attempt didn't work in any version:

```
app.buttons.elementBoundByIndex(2).tap()
```

And resulted in the following error:

> file:///%3Cunknown%3E: test failure: -[MyAppSnapshots testExample()] failed: UI Testing Failure - Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button 0x7f82d450ae30: traits: 8589934593, {{327.0, 613.5}, {35.0, 34.0}}, label: 'Kies', error: Error -25204 performing AXAction 2003

Then from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33534187/189431) I grabbed the solution of `forceTapElement`, which does work on all but *iPhone 6(s) Plus*.

```
app.buttons.elementBoundByIndex(2).forceTapElement()
```

Then I tried tapping on a coordinate;

```
let window = app.windows.elementBoundByIndex(0)
let rightBottom = window.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(
  CGRectGetWidth(window.frame) - 20,
  CGRectGetHeight(window.frame) - 20
))
rightBottom.tap()
```

But that again didn't work on any of the devices.

So how do I test these native interfaces? Or should I just add some kind of switch to my code so that the `UIImagePickerController` is replaced by something non-interactive.

Comment: Were You able to fix this issue? As I am currently facing it too! I did try all the mentioned solutions, but nothing works on any of the devices, unless I did set the .allowsEditing = false.

Comment: No, never found a solution. Although it now has been quite some time that I tried it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In case you still need it (or anyone else), I were able to fix it by just putting sleep(1) before tapping the Choose button. Not sure if that should be the case for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like working approach:

```
func waitForElementToAppear(element: XCUIElement,
                            timeout seconds: TimeInterval = 5,
                            file: String = #file,
                            line: UInt = #line) {
    let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    let expectation = expectation(for: existsPredicate, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)
    XCTWaiter().wait(for: [expectation], timeout: seconds)
    XCTAssert(element.exists, "Element \(element.identifier) not found")
}

func tapAtPosition(position: CGPoint,
                   file: String = #file,
                   line: UInt = #line) {
    let cooridnate = app.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)).withOffset(CGVector(dx: position.x, dy: position.y))
    cooridnate.tap()
}

func selectPhotoFromGalary(index: Int = 0) {
    waitForElementToAppear(element: app.buttons["Photos"], timeout: 10)
    let position = app.images.containing(NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH 'Photo'")).element(boundBy: index).frame.origin
    tapAtPosition(position: position)
    let chooseButton = app.buttons["Choose"]
    waitForElementToAppear(element: chooseButton, timeout: 5)
    chooseButton.tap()
}
```