# Recording tap on UISegmentedControl gets assertion fail during test

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I have a segmented control with three buttons, labeled "I", "II" and curiously enough "III".

When I run in the simulator and record, it emits code of the form:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.buttons["I"].tap()
app.buttons["II"].tap()
app.buttons["III"].tap()
```

When I execute this test, it crashes on the tap() with an exception of the form:

```
Assertion Failure: <unknown>:0: Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button, label: 'I', error: Error -25204 performing AXAction 2003 on element
```

I tried drilling down to the button through its segmented control as such:

```
let presetCtl = app.segmentedControls["preset"]
presetCtl.children(matching: .button).element(boundBy: 0).tap()
```

But this produces the same assertion failure on the call to tap():

```
Assertion Failure: <unknown>:0: Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button,label: 'I', error: Error -25204 performing AXAction 2003 on element...
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh f*** me, this looks like a bug in XCode that I found a workaround for here: [Xcode UI test - UI Testing Failure - Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) when tap on Search field "Cancel' button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422681/xcode-ui-test-ui-testing-failure-failed-to-scroll-to-visible-by-ax-action)

You would think that the buttons synthesized inside of a `UISegmentedControl` would have their `isHittable` property set to `true`, but, that is what you would get for thinking... Love ya !