# Add button in SwiftUI Stepper not hittable during XCTest

Tags: swiftui, xctest, watchos

My stepper is defined as follows (Standalone WatchOS app)

```
Stepper(value: $myCount) {
    Text("\(myCount)").font(.footnote).accessibilityIdentifier("count_label")
}.accessibilityIdentifier("my_stepper")
```

It is fully functional on the real / simulator devices. During a test case, defined below, I am unable to invoke the increment button. (I get an error and the button itself is not hittable, ever)

```
XCTAssertTrue(app.steppers["my_stepper"].waitForExistence(timeout: 10))
XCTAssertFalse(app.steppers["my_stepper"].buttons["Remove"].isEnabled)
XCTAssertTrue(app.steppers["my_stepper"].buttons["Add"].isEnabled)
-> (Error)  app.steppers["my_stepper"].buttons["Add"].tap()
```

> Error kAXErrorCannotComplete performing AXAction
> kAXScrollToVisibleAction on element AX element pid

I tried to [forceTap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33534187/5655414) (using coordinates) with no luck. Any idea how to invoke the increment action?

Comment: Did you try to generate the code with recorder to see how Xcode sees those buttons? Also, just an advice: Insead of constantly using `app.steppers["my_stepper"]`, you better declare it as a variable and just access it.

Comment: If it is the only stepper on the screen, I think you can try something like `let stepper = app.otherElements["Stepper"].firstMatch`

Comment: what is a recorder? any links so i can try?

Comment: yes, check 04:40 : `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECuc3qoRm90`.

Comment: i'll give that a go. that might uncover the mystery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the increment and decrement buttons exist in the view stack, they are not hittable. Likely a bug in SwiftUI that impacts either WatchOS or all platforms. Best way I have found to **temporarily** get past the issue is using the following [tutorial](https://medium.com/twinkl-educational-publishers/accessible-swiftui-for-easy-ui-testing-f2e7b8824b39) :

```
app.steppers["my_stepper"].coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.9, dy: 0.5)).tap()
```

This is a workaround that will probably fail on different devices. For me, it would only work with **Ultra 49mm watchOS 9.0**. Accepting this until a better answer is found.